# c++ Issue with passing ifstream argument in to header member method

Tags: c++, file, header, arguments, ifstream

This is my first question so pardon me if I don't look like I've done my homework regarding what I'm going to ask, i assure you I've scanned many internet pages for the answer.

I've been stuck with a small problem for the last hour and a half or so, the answer should probably be clear to me but I cant seem to work it out. I'm writing a member function "void read()" of class "ArrayStorage".

I'm using header files.

---

**`ArrayStorage.h`**

```
#include <fstream> // Reading/Writing from file requires this standard library.
#include <iostream> // Needed for cin and cout
#include <ostream> // Needed for outputting to output file
#include <string> // Needed for string values
using namespace std;

#pragma once

class ArrayStorage
{
public:

    void read(ifstream &fin1); //reads data from a file
    void write(ofstream &out1); //output data to an output stream(ostream)
    bool exists(); //return true or false depending whether or not a given word exists
    void stdExists(); //^^ use either std::count() or std::find() inside here

};
```

**`ArrayStorage.cpp`**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayStorage.h"
using namespace std;


void ArrayStorage::read(ifstream &fin1)
{
    int index = 0;
    char *array[5];

    ifstream fin(fin1);
        if(fin.is_open())
        {
            char c;
            while(fin.good())
            {
                fin.get(c);
                fin >> *array[index];
                cout << array[index];
                index++;
            }

            fin.close();
        }
}

void ArrayStorage::write(ofstream &out1)
{
    ofstream fout(out1);

    fout.close();
}
```

**`Main.cpp`**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ArrayStorage.h"
#include "LinkedListStorage.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    string find = "pixel";

    ifstream fin1("data.txt");
    ofstream out1("dataout.txt");

    if(!fin1.is_open()) 
    {
        cout << "FAIL" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ArrayStorage arrayStorage1;

    // read in values into data structure
    arrayStorage1.read(fin1);

    // output values in data structure to file
    arrayStorage1.write(out1);

    fin1.close();
    out1.close();
        return 0;
}
```

### Error:

> Error 1   error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'    c:\program files (x86)...

### Question:

What is the error I'm making here? Any help would be appreciated. Also i am aware there is a lot of useless code in there but ignore that I'm just trying to establish my read file method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no public copy constructors for classes ifstream and ofstream, and you are trying to call them when you do:

```
ifstream fin(fin1);
```

and

```
ofstream fout(out1);
```

In your case, just rewrite the read() and write() functions to use fin1 and out1 directly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

I've changed it to "ifstream fin;"

However now my program is not detecting the open file and is instead skipping the following code:

 `if(fin.is_open())
        {
            char c;
            while(fin.good())
            {
                fin.get(c);
                fin >> *array[index];
                cout << array[index];
                index++;
            }

            fin.close();
        }`